# How do I show my local WordPress site to someone?

Tags: wordpress

I am doing a work from home web development internship. I was asked by the recruiter to make a website on WordPress. I have done the work but the site is hosted on the localhost as of now. How do I show it to my recruiter in order to get the weekly feedback on my work? I have never worked on WordPress before. Is there any way out?

Comment: What about Skype, Teamviewer or Slack video call?

Comment: If they just want to see script then I would prefer github

Comment: No they want to see the website front end and functionality.

Comment: Then skype option is good one for me

Comment: Ask them how they want you to show them

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is not programming related.  At best, it might qualify as server administration, at which point it is on the wrong Stack community.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the same network then you can follow these steps to show your site to someone.

go to `Admin Panel > Settings > General` and replace your `localhost` with your `ip-address` for WordPress `Address (URL)` and Site Address (URL) and see if it works. Also, don't forget to put your `WAMP/XAmpp` server online.

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180207/how-to-make-other-computer-in-local-network-see-my-theme)

If you are not in the same network then you should use `Skype or TeamViewer` to show your site.